# Dispatch CANoe using python COM

Tags: python, python-2.7, com, win32com, canoe

I'm trying to open CANoe application using python win32com, but i'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\20044033\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in <module>
   xl = win32com.client.Dispatch ('CANoe.Application')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

**com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)**

Whereas no such error for other applications like excel.
From other stackoverflow answers i understood that only COM registered applications can be accessed.

How to add CANoe into the list of registered COM objects?

Comment: Not providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) doesn't help, but as far as I know CANoe registers itself during installation so I doubt it's the reason unless something went wrong during your installation.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Answer (score -1):

Good morning actually i'm working on the same project i used to have the same problem as you you just need to check the name of your CANoe configuration and put the correct path in the python code here is my code and the measurement setup in CANoe.
Good luck !!

Comment: you should put this as a comment, it s not really an answer and potentially make confusion with real answers ;)

Comment: You say _here's my code_ and then provide none. Also you should be able to launch CANoe not specifying any configuration file (with a sole `win332com.client.Dispatch("CANoe.Application"`).

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: there's one caveat I guess - CANoe has to know what configuration load as a default if you don't provide any.